# Oracle delete without disabling constraint

Tags: oracle, constraints, delete-row

I'm using Oracle 11g. I'm a developer with basic SQL knowledge. (:S)

I need to create a delete query but my DB user does not have the permission for disabling constraints.

I have the following structure.

```
TABLE CARD_HOLDER
CARD_HOLDER_ID
... (other fields)
```

/

```
TABLE CARD
Card_ID
... (other fields)
```

/

```
TABLE SERVICE
SERVICE_ID
SERVICE_DESCRIPTION (credit, debit, etc...)
```

/

```
TABLE CARD_HOLDER_SERVICES
CARD_HOLDER_ID
SERVICE_ID
... (other fields)
```

I need to delete all data from CARD_HOLDERS who have a service of type "service=10". So I'd delete the **card, other tables related to the card holder** that I don't show here for the sake of brevity, and at last the **CARD_HOLDER_SERVICES** and the **CARD_HOLDER** itselt.

The thing is, in order to delete the card holder, I need to know if it has the **service=10**, and if I delete the **CARD_HOLDER_SERVICES** first I don't have that information anymore to filter the card holders that I need to delete.

I've checked in the table **CARD_HOLDER_SERVICES** that the CARD_HOLDER_ID constraint is of type **NOT DEFERRABLE**.

The only thing I could think of doing and I don't know how to, neither whether it's going to work or not, is to create a temporary table with the CARD_HOLDER_IDs that I want to delete, then remove the **CARD_HOLDER_SERVICES** and last the **CARD_HOLDER**.

Can anyone tell me what is the easiest and best way to do it?

Performance isn't an issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on data volumes and performance requirements, I'd probably just write some procedural code.  If I understand your requirements, something like

```
BEGIN
  FOR chs IN (SELECT *
                FROM card_holder_services
               WHERE service_id = 10)
  LOOP
    FOR ch IN (SELECT *
                 FROM card_holder
                WHERE card_holder_id = chs.card_holder_id)
    LOOP
      DELETE FROM card
       WHERE card_id = ch.card_id;
    END LOOP;

    DELETE FROM card_holder
     WHERE card_holder_id = chs.card_holder_id;

    DELETE FROM card_holder_services
     WHERE card_holder_id = chs.card_holder_id
       AND service_id     = 10;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you're interested in pure efficiency, you could do individual `DELETE` statements that end up duplicating a fair amount of code

```
DELETE FROM card
 WHERE card_id IN (SELECT ch.card_id
                     FROM card_holder ch
                          JOIN card_holder_services chs
                            ON( ch.card_holder_id = chs.card_holder_id )
                    WHERE chs.service_id = 10);

DELETE FROM card_holder
 WHERE card_holder_id IN (SELECT card_holder_id
                            FROM card_holder_services chs
                           WHERE chs.service_id = 10);

DELETE FROM card_holder_services
 WHERE service_id = 10;
```

Comment: I don't know about the first procedure approach. But if I try to delete the card_holder before the card_holder_service as in the second approach it'll give me a constraint error. Because it's being used. I'll try the procedure and as soon as I have a feedback I'll let you know.

Comment: I just adapted the first approach to my real schema and It worked like a charm. The for loops solved my problem. Thank you very much. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use collection (up to let's say 50-80k records).

So first fetch card_holder_id into collection, in my example c_serv and then make delete statement according to this id. If you use FORALL statement to loop through collection, it will be faster than classical FOR LOOP.

```
declare
   type t_c_serv is table of number;
   c_serv t_c_serv; 
begin
   select card_holder_id bulk collect into c_serv from card_holder_services where service_id=10;

  FORALL i IN c_serv.FIRST..c_serv.LAST
    DELETE FROM card where card_holder_id=c_serv(i);
  FORALL i IN c_serv.FIRST..c_serv.LAST
    DELETE FROM card_holder_services where card_holder_id=c_serv(i);
  FORALL i IN c_serv.FIRST..c_serv.LAST
    DELETE FROM card_holder where card_holder_id=c_serv(i);

end;
```

Note, that I assumed that card table contains card_holder_id, you can adjust it according to your design, e.g. if instead there is card_id in card_holder then replace delete from card by

```
DELETE FROM card WHERE card_id in 
 (select card_id from card_holder where card_holder_id=c_serv(i)).
```